# API to get user data in a spcific area/zipcode with a interest

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

Can you provide guidance on obtaining user data based on a particular postal code and specific interests?

for example user with a interest in basketball and in a postal code of
73001

The Facebook Marketing API offers separate APIs for retrieving users based on specific interests and users within a particular zip code. However, there isn't an API that combines both criteria.

For more details, you can refer to the documentation: [Facebook Marketing API - Targeting Search](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences/reference/targeting-search#zipcode)